# The automorphism of splitting field of x^p-x+a over Z_p.

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, automorphism-group

I'd like to solve the question.

Let $L$ the splitting field of $f(x)=x^p-x+a$ ($a\neq 0$) over $\mathbb Z_p$.

1. $g : L \rightarrow L$, $g(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ is automorphism.
2. $\text{Aut}(L/\mathbb Z_p)=\mathbb Z_p$?

I solved the follwings fact

- $f$ has no root in $\mathbb Z_p$
- If $\alpha$ is root of $\mathbb Z_p$, then $\alpha+1$ is root of $\mathbb Z_p$
- $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$
- The number of irreducible of which order is $p$ over $\mathbb Z_p$ is $p^{p-1} -1$

I tried to use the frobenius automorphism, but I failed.

How to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Why was EDITING [the earlier version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3655042/11619) into shape not an option for you?

Comment: Sorry about jumping on your case a bit. Just giving you a crash course on how the site works. For example, did you know that all users with at least 10000 points can still see the deleted version simply by clicking the link in my first comment. New users often think that deletion is a permanent thing, allowing a fresh start, but that is not how it works. The site software keeps track of such things. If you leave too many orphaned questions like that in your wake, it will place (automatic and non-negotiable) limitations on your ability to ask.

Comment: Not much harm done by a single such question, I think. But this is something you should be aware of. The rules imposed by the software really want you to edit the less than successful question into shape rather than delete it and repost it.

Comment: Now that you got a good answer here, it is best to leave things as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of [Artin–Schreier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory).

Since $x^p-x-a$ is irreducible (using your remark n.3), then $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ (with $\alpha$ a root of $f(x)$) is the splitting field of $f(x)$. Also, if $\alpha$ is a root, then the set of roots of $f(x)$ is
$$
\{\alpha, \alpha+1,...,\alpha+p-1\}
$$
that are distinct and exactly $p$ (I used your second remark). Hence the field extension $L=\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb F_p$ is a Galois extension of degree $p$ (because $\alpha$ has degree $p$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and it's minimal polynomial is separable).

The map $g:L\rightarrow L$ such that $g(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ is well defined: infact, to define a $g:L\rightarrow L$ it's sufficient to define the image of $\alpha$ and this image has to be a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Since $\alpha+1$ is a root of $f(x)$ that is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $g$ is well defined. Also, since $L$ over $\mathbb F_p$ is normal, then $g(L) = L$ and $g$ is an automorphism.

To compute $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb F_p)$ is sufficient to notice that is a group of cardinality equal to $p$, so it is cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$. Moreover a generator of this group is the automorphism $g$ that has order $p$.

Comment: Thanks! Then i have one question. Why L=F_2(alpha) over F_2 not F_p? Umm, although it is F_p, it is also galois extension. So..?

Comment: @Chanr13 Yes is always $\mathbb F_p$, Typo mistake. Thanks, I edited

Comment: THANKS! but i'm sorry, i don't understand 3 part,  1. There are exactly p-solutions? : i understand a+b (b in Z_p) is a root, but there exist another solution which form is not a+b.  2. I want to see the map is homorphism, what's the process? 3. L is normal extension then g(L)=L? Why? Thanks for kind. I started the galois theory 3 days ago, so i unriped at field thoery. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) 1. A polynomial of degree $p$ has exactly $p$ solutions counting with multiplicity (think at degree); the roots we found are exactly $p$ and they are distinct, so the polynomial $f(x)$ is equal to $(x-\alpha)\cdots (x-(\alpha + p -1))$ and there are not any roots. 3. An extension $L/K$ is normal if for all $\varphi:L\rightarrow \overline K$ such that $\varphi_{|_K} = id_K$ then $\varphi(L)=L$ (this is the definition of normal extension). Since $L$ is normal and $g{|_{\mathbb F_p}} = id_{\mathbb F_p}$, then $g(L)=L$.

Comment: For question 2. You don't have to verify explicity that is a morphism. It comes from general theorem about extension of field homomorphism. I think you can find some reference online. Anyway in this case you can consider the isomorphism $\mathbb F_p[x]/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ given by the map $p(x)\mapsto p(\alpha)$ (evaluation in $\alpha$) and the isomorphism $\mathbb F_p[x]/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb F_p(\alpha+1)$ given by the map $p(x)\mapsto p(\alpha+1)$ (evaluation in $\alpha+1$).

Comment: Wow. Thanks, i understand process1, then i know the definition of normal extension is  "K: algebraic extension & if irreducible polynomial has root in K, the others(roots) are also in K." Thus, the process 3 don't understand.

Comment: If you now compose the two isomorphisms, you have $g:\mathbb F_p(\alpha)\cong \mathbb F_p[x]/f(x) \cong \mathbb F_p(\alpha+1)$ that is exactly your map and it is a morphism because it is composition of morphisms.

Comment: @Chanr13 [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Normal_Extension) you can find the equivalence between the definitions of normality

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!